# Creating Appcelerator  application

Tags: appcelerator

I am trying to use appcelerator to develop some cross platform mobile applications, but I can't get it to work

note : I am getting same issues using mac and windows ( pics are from my windows try )

1- when creating a new project i get this : http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/7148/capturewa.png
i tried to change lot of stuff but the project isn't getting created...

2- in a trial to get around that problem i decided to import the kitchen sink app
but when trying to lunch the application the android sdk version doesn't load up leaving me unable to run the emulator

and when testing with a mac the android tab has the same issue while the iphone sdk tab shows the version but when trying to lunch it at the last step i get that an error occurred and that i have to check the output file ( there is none !! )

so my question.. what did i do wrong ?
                 how to fix it ?
                 any other not so buggy platforms out there for simple cross platform app development ?

or just simply can some one tell me his setup ( of sdk versions ) that works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive had some issues lately, what I did to get around them was to start the project with version 1.2 and then immediately go into the project and change it to 1.3. that seems to fix it.